# Listing Attribute Table in order of Selected objects

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table, python-addin, order

Currently when I open my attribute table, I get the order or points by which they are added and I would like to get them in order in which I selected them.

For example,
I select points (in order): 6, 24,3,91
and in my attribute table it shows the points in OBJECT_ID value from lowest to highest.
3,6,24,91

However I would want these to come up in the order I select them. Any ideas how to change this. I'm sure its staring me right in the face.

I have tried to change Advances Sorting to be turned off but this still doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: Not that I know of. Irrespective of which order they're selected in they all end up in the layers FeatureSelection which is enumerated by OID/FID.

Comment: It's *not* staring you in the face.  The order in which records have been selected is not saved in a selection set, so there isn't anything to sort by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version of ArcGIS for Desktop, if you are using 10.1 or later, I think you could write a Python Add-In to perform the selection one feature at a time and update a field with the order of selection so that you can sort on it.

However, I cannot think of a use case to justify the effort of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Tables can only be sorted based on values within the table.  If you were to know what order you were going to select the rows in ahead of time, then you could add a sort column and assign values to that column in order to provide the sort you are looking for.

I had a number of items I had to iterate through repeatedly on a file that was routinely changing and used this technique.  It seemed to be less work than other options.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who may be interested.
There seems to be no way to order these. The easiest way to achieve what I am interested in, is to click on the left hand side of the table to highlight the entire row in yellow. 
In doing this, it also highlights the point on the map in yellow so you can see which point is being used.

This will take slightly longer to do what I am trying to achieve but better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: What you describe is how it shows selected selected (no that's not a typo) features (and there can be more than one at a time). I'm unsure on how this would sort the attribute table in the order of selection, so what you are interested/trying to achieve in appears to be different than the original question. Unless you're using that ability to then create/populate a custom sort field.